# Complicated background work in UWP, is it real?

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, windows-8.1-universal

Usually I work with Android but now I need to make background application/library/service in UWP.

So, I need three background tasks/jobs/services:

1. Every 15 minutes send POST request to the server
2. Every 1 minute check some data
3. Run via push notification a long-running tcp/ip connection which can run about 1 hour (how long can it run?)

I am confused, is it possible for UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer,it is not complicated.

> Every 15 minutes send POST request to the server

Background tasks can run as frequently as every 15 minutes, and they can be set to run at a certain time by using the [`TimeTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224843). For more info see [Run a background task on a timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-).

> Every 1 minute check some data

Based on battery life considerations if `FreshnessTime` is set to less than 15 minutes, an exception is thrown when attempting to register the background task. For long running background Task please check [Run background tasks indefinitely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly#run-background-tasks-indefinitely) official document.

> Run via push notification a long-running tcp/ip connection which can run about 1 hour (how long can it run?)

You could use [`PushNotificationTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) to enable them to provide real-time communication with the user even when the app is not in the foreground.

For creating the Background Task, You could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task). And this is official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) that you could refer.